# How to make multi level dynamic navigation in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I try to create a step by step navigation, like this:
[image: Navigation explanation]

And I know how to make it real with jQuery, but I started using AngularJs and I think it should be easy with it, but can't find idea how to make it without DOM manipulations in model. I'm newbiew with Angular. Hope for your advice, and links to documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use ui-router: https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/

Answer (score 0):

Eurika! I did it with array and inner arrays per each level :)